# What is the DAX expression to filter data in a table by a Start date entered by Slicer Input?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner and doing the first project in Power BI.

I have Dates table with "Date" column having first day of each month from 2020 to 2025 like - 1/1/2020,2/1/2020.....12/1/2025.

I have Orders table with "Date" column (having first day of each month from 2020 to 2025 like - 1/1/2020,2/1/2020.....12/1/2025) and Costs column.

I have a slicer "Start Date" with options like 1/1/2020,2/1/2020.....12/1/2025.

Problem Statement - After I select a Start Date value for example 10/1/2023, I have to get range of dates like 10/1/2023,11/1/2023...12/1/2025 from 'Dates'[Date].

1. The lower limit of the range will be my selected date.
2. Upper limit will always be the maximum date value of Dates table.

What I can do -
I can generate a series of last 12 months from selected date.
So, for selected date 10/1/2023 the range would be 11/1/2022 to 10/1/2023.

```
VAR PrevDates=DATESINPERIOD('Dates'[Date],RefDate,-12,MONTH) 
//RefDate holds the selected date
```

What I need to do-
But how can I get the range of dates from the selected StartDate to the maximum date present in dates table?

Answer (score 0):

In Slicer setting, choose 'After'. Then you can choose any start date and get the range of dates from the selected StartDate to the maximum date.

[image]